# Calculating tax on one item in Python

Tags: python

This is a shopping cart for the user the calculates their total and lists the products. I am having difficulty defining the tax at the bottom "wdeposit" I have a few more to do. and then how to show two separate totals.
then I was going to use

```
while 1:
    action=input("press any key if you like to purchase otherwise type end to finish")
    if action=="end"
        break
```

I hope that will be a good end to this. Hope someone can help me with the end of my homework. Hints would be more helpful so I can learn and not actually have someone do it for me. Thanks.

```
#Welcome user to user display product and prices
print("Hello, welcome to the store")
print("This is the list & products")
print("0,Milk,$2.39/Gallon")
print("2,Eggs,$1.58/per dozen")
print("4,Water,$1.00/Bottle+$.05 deposit")
print("6,Soda,$.99/Can+$.05 deposit")
print("8,Bread,$2.99/Loaf")
print("10,Chips,$1.30/Bag")
print("12,Tomato,$1.99/Pound")
print("Ready-food box,$8.99/Box+$.0625 tax")

#Prompt users for his product
totalpurchase=0
choice=int(input("Enter your product code"))
if choice==0:
           qofmilk=int(input("How many gallons do you wish to purchase?"))
           totmilk=qofmilk*2.39
           print("Your total price for milk is", totmilk)
           totalpurchase=totalpurchase+totmilk
if choice==2:
            qofeggs=int(input("How many dozen of eggs do you wish to purchase?"))
            toteggs=qofeggs*1.58
            print("Your total price for eggs is", toteggs)
            totalpurchase=totalpurchase+toteggs
if choice==4:
            qofwater=int(input("How many bottles of water do you wish to purchase?"))
            totwater=qofwater*1.00
            print("Your total price for water is", totwater)
            totalpurchase=totalpurchase+totwater
if choice==6:
            qofsoda=int(input("How many cans of soda do you wish to purchase?"))
            totsoda=totsoda*.99
            print("Your total price for soda is", totsoda)
            totalpurchase=totalpurchase+totsoda
if choice==8:
            qofbread=int(input("How many loafs of bread do you wish to purchase?"))
            totbread=totbread*2.99
            print("Your total price for bread is", totbread)
            totalpurchase=totalpurchase+totbread
if choice==10:
            qofchips=int(input("How many bags of chips do you wish to purchase?"))
            totchips=totchips*1.30
            print("Your total price for chips is", totchips)
            totpurchase=totalpurchase+totchips
if choice==12:
            qoftomato=int(input("How many pounds of tomatoes do you wish to purchase?"))
            tottomato=tottomato*1.99
            print ("Your total price for tomatoes is", tottomato)
            totpurchase=totpurchase+tottomato
if choice==14:
            qofchicken=int(input("How man pounds of chicken do you wish to purchase?"))
            totchicken=totchicken*2.99
            print("Your total price for chicken is", totchicken)
            totpurchase=totpurchase+totchicken
if choice==16:
            qofready=int(input("How many boxes of ready-food boxes do you wish to purchase?"))
            totready=totready*8.99
            print("Your total price for ready-food boxes is", qofready)
            totpurchase=totpurchase+totready
if choice==4:
            wdeposit=wdeposit*.05
            print("$.05 deposit", wdeposit)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `wdeposit=wdeposit*.05` should probably be based on the number of bottles of water (`qofwater * 0.05`). You have `if choice==4:` twice, but you only need it once. You can put the `wdeposit` calculation in the same block where you ask the user how many bottles of water they want to buy.